# How do I implement option buttons and change the button color in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

Pls suggest how can I change the color of the button when I pressed it, and the color of the first button will be changed to the default color when I pressed the second button.

For example, After I clicked the STRAIGHT Button, the button will become green color and when I click the LEFT button the LEFT button will change to green color and the STRAIGHT button will become the default color which is white color. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

CODE:

```
def draw_button(self):

    global clicked
    action = False

    # get mouse position
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # create pygame Rect object for the button
    button_rect = Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    # check mouseover and clicked conditions
    if button_rect.collidepoint(pos):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
            clicked = True
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.click_col, button_rect)
        elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0 and clicked == True:
            clicked = False
            action = True
           
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.hover_col, button_rect)
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.button_col, button_rect)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the color of a button once it is clicked in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753511/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-a-button-once-it-is-clicked-in-pygame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you draw the button, you have to set the color dependent on the global variable `clicked`:

```py
def draw_button(self):

    global clicked
    
    # get mouse position
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # create pygame Rect object for the button
    button_rect = Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    # check mouseover and clicked conditions
    hover = button_rect.collidepoint(pos)
    if hover and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
        clicked = not clicked

    color = self.button_col
    if clicked:
        color = self.click_col
    elif hover:
        color = self.hover_col

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, button_rect)
```

Anyway, that won't satisfy you, because [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) returns a list of Boolean values ​​that represent the state (`True` or `False`) of all mouse buttons. The state of a button is `True` as long as a button is held down.
You have to use `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event. The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs once when you click the mouse button and the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event occurs once when the mouse button is released. The [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object has two attributes that provide information about the mouse event. `pos` is a tuple that stores the position that was clicked. `button` stores the button that was clicked.

---

If you have multiple buttons that you have to interact with each other, a single `clicked` status is not enough. You need a separate "clicked" state for each button. If the clicked state of 1 button becomes `True`, the states of the other keys must be set to `False`. I recommend to implement a `RadioButton` class for this.

See also [Mouse](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_mouse_and_mosuse_events.md) and [Sprite](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_sprite_and_sprite_mask.md).

Minimal example:
<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RadioButton](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RadioButton#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

class RadioButton(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, font, text):
        super().__init__() 
        text_surf = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
        self.button_image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.button_image.fill((96, 96, 96))
        self.button_image.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = (w // 2, h // 2)))
        self.hover_image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.hover_image.fill((96, 96, 96))
        self.hover_image.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = (w // 2, h // 2)))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.hover_image, (96, 196, 96), self.hover_image.get_rect(), 3)
        self.clicked_image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.clicked_image.fill((96, 196, 96))
        self.clicked_image.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = (w // 2, h // 2)))
        self.image = self.button_image
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.clicked = False
        self.buttons = None

    def setRadioButtons(self, buttons):
        self.buttons = buttons

    def update(self, event_list):
        hover = self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if hover and event.button == 1:
                    for rb in self.buttons:
                        rb.clicked = False
                    self.clicked = True
        
        self.image = self.button_image
        if self.clicked:
            self.image = self.clicked_image
        elif hover:
            self.image = self.hover_image


pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font50 = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)

radioButtons = [
    RadioButton(50, 40, 200, 60, font50, "option 1"),
    RadioButton(50, 120, 200, 60, font50, "option 2"),
    RadioButton(50, 200, 200, 60, font50, "option 3")
]
for rb in radioButtons:
    rb.setRadioButtons(radioButtons)
radioButtons[0].clicked = True

group = pygame.sprite.Group(radioButtons)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    group.update(event_list)

    window.fill(0)
    group.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
your_button_rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
color = (0,0,0)
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
def change_button_color():
    if your_button_rect.colliderect(pos):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #checks if mouse button is pressed down while the cursor is on the rectangle
            color = (your_desired_Color_RGBvalue)

while True:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,your_button_rect)
    change_button_color()
```